# Add hover message on icon in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, mousehover

I would like to add a hover message which will appear when I move my mouse above the "i" information icon.

[info icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF7jD.png)

I added the icon with:

```
numericInput("fixed_ratio", 
             label = tags$div(HTML('Fixed ratio <i class="fas fa-info-circle" 
                                       style = "color:#0072B2;"></i>')), 
             value = 1)
```

Within the "HTML", I tried to add "title" to work as the hover message, but it didn't work out.

Is there any way to add the message? Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    "fixed_ratio", 
    label = tags$span(
      "Fixed ratio", 
      tags$i(
        class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign", 
        style = "color:#0072B2;",
        title = "message"
      )
    ), 
    value = 1
  )  
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output){})
```

Comment: Hi Stephane! Thanks for your solution, but it still doesn't work for me. No message showed up when I move my mouse over the icon. Did you library any other package to make it work?

Comment: @XinyingFang The code I posted works "as is". Maybe try with another browser.

Comment: Thanks! It worked out finally after I added a bsTooltip function on the icon to enable the hoover message. May be some functions contradict? I cannot enable the hoover message without the bsTooltip function.

Comment: @Chinyako, can you please share your solution with the bsTooltip add-on ? I don't manage to make the solution work as it is proposed.

Comment: @Vincent I uploaded my shiny code at [link](https://github.com/vivid225/REAP-1/blob/main/REAP-1/app.R). The specific code is around line 185.